# Mostrar diferencias entre dos tablas SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

espero me puedan ayudar, he buscados por Google pero sin encontrar lo que necesito, no se si se pueda hacer o no, tengo 2 tablas sql (personal1 y personal2)

en **personal1** tengo ***codigoe,nombre,valor1,valor2,valor3*** y en **personal2** los mismos campos, lo que quiero hacer es que se pueda comparar por codigoe las diferencias respecto a personal2, e.g.

```
personal1
codigoe        nombre         valor1        valor2      valor3
1              luis           0.00          10.00       20.00

personal2
codigoe        nombre         valor1        valor2      valor3
1              luis           1.00          5.00       20.00
```

y el resultado que busco es

```
resultado
codigoe        nombre         valor1        valor2      valor3
    1              luis           1.00          -5.00       0.00
```

de antemano muchas gracias,

PD. ya tengo una consulta que muestra que un registro cambio pero lo que necesito es ver la variaciones por cada campo en la tabla, ya sea si disminuyo o aumento

Answer (score 2):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Con esta consulta deberías obtener el resultado esperado:

```
  SELECT 
        p1.codigoe, 
        p1.nombre, 
        (p2.valor1-p1.valor1) valor1, 
        (p2.valor2-p1.valor2) valor2, 
        (p2.valor3-p1.valor3) valor3 
    FROM personal2 p2 
        INNER JOIN personal1 p1 ON p2.codigoe=p1.codigoe;
```

Se trata de unir las dos tablas usando la columna `codigoe` y restar los valores correspondientes, pero poniendo como primer valor de la operación la columna de la tabla `p2`.

`p1` y `p2` son *alias* para no hacer tan larga la consulta.

**Salida:**

```
codigoe      nombre     valor1     valor2     valor3
-------------------------------------------------------
    1        luis       1,00       -5,00      0,00
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.